# Generating missing years for a sequence SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table I need to analyze and for some years the data is missing and I'd like to reflect that. The first two columns are location codes, while the last two are the latest years entered. I'm able to get the min and max for each location but I'd like to create a sequence like this to join against another table. Each one of the locations have a different range of years so essentially I'd have to do create a separate range given the min and max for each location.

Given results

```
(Location Cds)  Start   End
0160,   002,    1995,   2009
0160,   001,    1995,   1997
```

Goal results

```
(Location Cds)  Years
0160,   001,    1995
0160,   001,    1996
0160,   001,    1997
0160,   002,    1995
0160,   002,    1996
0160,   002,    1997
0160,   002,    1998
0160,   002,    1999
0160,   002,    2000
0160,   002,    2001
0160,   002,    2002
0160,   002,    2003
0160,   002,    2004
0160,   002,    2005
0160,   002,    2006
0160,   002,    2007
0160,   002,    2008
0160,   002 ,   2009
```

Comment: This is where a tally table make a world of difference. Can you post your table definition? Or at the the very least what these pieces of data are?

Comment: @SeanLange I'm essentially partitioning by the location codes and grabbing the first and last year I have for those records. From that data set I want to create the second set, filling in any years between the Start and the End.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tally table is the answer to this challenge. It has been called the "Swiss Army Knife of t-sql" and for good reason. It can do all sorts of things where people normally think of a loop. Here is an excellent article discussing the tally table by Jeff Moden. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

I like to keep a view on my system that generates 10,000 rows nearly instantly with zero reads. Here is that view.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
GO
```

Then when you have challenging queries like the one you are working with it is pretty simple. Here is a fully working example including ddl for the problem you posted. In your case you would run this type of query directly against your table. I used a table variable because I don't have your table to work with.

```
declare @Something table 
(
    Location varchar(10)
    , Cds varchar(10)
    , YearStart int
    , YearEnd int
)

insert @Something
(
    Location
    , Cds
    , YearStart
    , YearEnd
) values
('0160', '002', 1995, 2009)
, ('0160', '001', 1995, 1997)

select s.Location
    , s.Cds
    , Years = x.N 
from @Something s
cross apply
(
    select *
    from cteTally t
    where t.N >= s.YearStart
        and t.N <= s.YearEnd
) x
order by s.Location 
    , s.Cds
    , x.N
```